# import Anaconda packages into sublime text 3 when using anaconda executable

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I've the following problem, I cannot import any packages when using anaconda executable on sublime text 3, my sublime build file works fine as i can run code but import packages throws me an error:

```
    the system is building correctly because i can print this text but numpy or any other package cannot be imported
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alexa\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\import.py", line 4, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "C:\Users\alexa\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\alexa\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . import _mklinit
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['C:\\Users\\alexa\\Anaconda3\\python', '-u', 'C:\\Users\\alexa\\AppData\\Roaming\\Sublime Text 3\\import.py']]
[dir: C:\Users\alexa\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3]
[path: C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\alexa\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;]
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, Just added the `C:\Users\Your_User_Name\Anaconda3\Library\bin` to my system variable on windows 10.